# Call python code after creation of a model instance in the admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin, models

I'm kinda lost, i need to call some python code after the creation of a model instance in the admin interface, and i've got no idea how to google for it.

Comment: Do you need it *only* after the admin instance, or for *all* instances anywhere?

Comment: Just when you save a model instance on the admin interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a function to listen on the [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#post-save), this will work whenever the model is created (irrespective of the means).

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, in fact i can use the pre_save signal to do other kind of things, tanks.

Answer (score 4):

Override the [`save_model()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method of a [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) you create for the model.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like django has quite sugar for a given task.